# How do i make the icon show correctly on the desktop icon

Tags: desktop-icons

I made a desktop link by creating a link in the desktop folder, which thin is displayed on the desktop. i selected the icon which then is correctly shown on the link in the folder but not on the desktop icon, even though the properties show it. (see pic)
what do i need to add / change?
[image]

Comment: The displayed icon needs to be defined in the `[Desktop Entry]` section of your `.desktop` file. If you do not have it set, add a line to the end of `[Desktop Entry]` that looks like `Icon=/home/kschindl/path/to/icon.png`. This should resolve the issue 

Comment: Thx to both comments. There is no desktop file, guess i have to create one. @N0rbert, yes this seems to be the case.